# AJAX won't insert data with single quotes into SQL

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have the following variable grabbing data from HTML:

```
    $workcarriedout = trim($_POST["workcarriedout"]);
```

And the following statement inserting this entry into SQL database (not a mySQL database):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (work_carried_out)
                    values ('".$workcarriedout."')");
```

This works perfectly fine until the data entered into the variable contains single quotes.

Could somebody please advise how I can get the data to import with the single quotes?

Edit: If this makes a difference here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('../settings.php');
// Get the form fields and remove whitespace
var_dump($_POST);

$datetime = trim($_POST["datetime"]);
$servername = trim($_POST["servername"]);
$carriedoutby = trim($_POST["carriedoutby"]);
$workverifiedby = trim($_POST["workverifiedby"]);
$authorisedby = trim($_POST["authorisedby"]);
$workcarriedout = trim($_POST["workcarriedout"]);
$howverified = trim($_POST["howverified"]);
$reason = trim($_POST["reason"]);
$impact = trim($_POST["impact"]);
$rollback = trim($_POST["rollback"]);


try {
    $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (date_time, server_name, carried_out_by, verified_by, authorised_by, work_carried_out, work_verified, change_reason, perceived_impact, rollback_process)
                    values ('$datetime','$servername','$carriedoutby','$workverifiedby','$authorisedby','$workcarriedout','$howverified','$reason','$impact','$rollback')");

$stmt->execute();



socket_close($socket);

?>
```

Comment: You would need to use prepare statement in the proper manner. Use bind parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to escape single code then insert to db:

```
$workcarriedout = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $workcarriedout);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (work_carried_out) values ('".$workcarriedout."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes you have in the string are breaking the SQL insert string. To avoid this try:

```
$escaped_string = $db->escape_string($workcarriedout); // does the job with the quotes

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (work_carried_out)
                values ('".$escaped_string."')");
```

Comment: Hi Machado - thanks for the comment, with this the request won't go through

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (`work_carried_out`)
                values ('\'$workcarriedout\'')");
```

I test it and it works now

somethings wrong but I cant see what, only difference between your and mine query is

```
(`date_time`, `server_name` etc..)
```

this is my query, and it works :/

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO zeljka (`name`,`lastName`) VALUES ('\'$st\'', '\'$sta\''); and it works :////
```

[screenshot inserted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcxPE.jpg)

Comment: Hi Zeljka - thanks for the comment, unfortunately this didn't work. Data went into the table without ' but not with

Comment: sorry my mistake, i didnt understood that you want in table with ', I will edit the answer

Comment: Hi Zeljka, this isn't working for me, below is how the code is currently looking: `$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (`date_time`, `server_name`, `carried_out_by`, `verified_by`, `authorised_by`, `work_carried_out`, `work_verified`, `change_reason`, `perceived_impact`, `rollback_process`)
                        values ('\'$datetime\'','\'$servername\'','\'$carriedoutby\'','\'$workverifiedby\'','\'$authorisedby\'','\'$escaped_string\'','\'$howverified\'','\'$reason\'','\'$impact\'','\'$rollback\'')");`

Comment: somethings wrong but I cant see what, only difference between your and mine query is (`date_time`, `server_name` etc..) mine query is $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO zeljka (`name`,`lastName`)
                VALUES ('\'$st\'', '\'$sta\''); and it works :////

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (work_carried_out)
                    values ('$workcarriedout')");
```

Comment: Hi Ankesh - thanks for the comment, this still gives me the same issue where data with single quotes in won't insert into the SQL table.